# How to get the time difference between 2 time spans when past midnight?

Tags: c#

I have a start time span and an end time span and I cannot figure out how to get the actual value.

```
TempoTotalParagem =  DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay - paragem.HoraInico;
```

well this was working untill it hit midnight.

I searched about this problem and that i needed to add a day.

So I tried

```
   TempoTotalParagem =  DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay - paragem.HoraInico + DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).TimeOfDay;


paragem.Hora Inicio = 23:14:00
DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay = 01:38
```

this gives

```
 TempoTotalParagem =  DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay - paragem.HoraInico + DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).TimeOfDay;

TempoTotalParagem = -19:55:59
```

I tried changing my variables for datetime but that is a bit complicated because on database the columns are timespans with data already. The purpose is to just count how much time has been since the start date though for the total time column

**EDIT**

```
{
    [Table("hParagensRegistos")]
    public class ParagemRegisto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm:ss}")]
        public TimeSpan HoraInico { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm:ss}")]
        public TimeSpan? HoraFim { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Time)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm:ss}")]
        public TimeSpan? TempoTotal { get; set; }

        public int RegistoId { get; set; }
        public Registo Registo {get;set;}

        public int? ParagemPlaneadaId { get; set; }
        public ParagemPlaneada ParagemPlaneada { get; set; }

        public int? ParagemNaoPlaneadaId { get; set; }
        public ParagemNaoPlaneada ParagemNaoPlaneada { get; set; }
    }
}
```

To avoid confusion here is the actual modal with the timespan properties.

```
startTime = HoraInico
```

Comment: Add 24 hours...

Comment: I tried add one day but didn't get the result expected tho, TimeSpan.FromHours(24) worked

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us more about that then. At the moment I'm not really sure that the problem you're experiencing is. Note that if you add a day to the date, you'll still get the same `TimeOfDay` value. You need to add 24 hours to the `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Feel free to use sample data that we can all copy/paste that reproduces the problem (what is the value of `paragem.HoraInico`)?

Comment: edited question to show what i tried that gave me the wrong result

Comment: What are the **values** of the input, and what is the expected output?

Comment: If `DateTime.Now` is `2019/06/26T00:37:00.000Z` and you add 1 day to it, you get `2019/06/27T00:37:00.000Z` and both of these have a time of day value of `00:37:00.000Z` because it's the same time of day 1 day later. Your current described solution (in your comment above) of adding `TimeSpan.FromHours(24)` is correct.

Comment: I see, i thought i had to use datetime to add one day, never thought about using timespan.fromhours or days

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]. As a general rule, you shouldn't do these kinds of calculations with `TimeSpan`. `TimeSpan` represents a **period** of time, not a **point** in time - so asking for the time difference between two time spans _almost_ never makes sense. Show a [mcve] (with at least 7 sample inputs and **expected results for each of those inputs**), explain **in detail** what you are trying to achieve and we can help.

Comment: If you're only comparing the times, then the solution appears correct. Why are you not include the date portion in the comparison? Still not clear what the expected output is.

Comment: Expected output is the total time past the start time, basically a counter

Comment: Don't use `TimeOfDay` when doing the comparison, because that sets the `Date` portion to zeroes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A start time and end time should also contain a date portion. If you include this when you get the difference, the results should be accurate.

For example:

```
// startTime is Midnight (which is technically the next day at time 0:00:00)
var startTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1); 

// endTime is 11:59pm tomorrow
var endTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59);

// Just subtract the values to get the difference
var timeLeft = endTime - startTime;

// timeLeft is 23:59
```

Some things to take into account here:

1. All `DateTime` objects have both a `Date` and `Time` portion.
2. `someDateTime.Date` (or `DateTime.Today`) returns the `Date` portion with the time zeroed out (midnight).
3. `someDateTime.TimeOfDay` returns a `TimeSpan` which represents the elapsed time since midnight and does not include a `Date` at all.

So if you are *just* comparing times, without regard to the `Date`, then the output you were getting was absolutely correct. But if you compare the full `DateTime` objects, you will get a `TimeSpan` that accurately reflects the full number of hours/minutes/seconds between the two.

Comment: I see, i tried changing my variables for datetime but that is a bit complicated because on database the columns are timespans with data already. The purpose is to just count how much time has been since the start date though for the total time column

Comment: This was part of my answer but there's no point posting it in full now, so here's a comment: If your start time is always the date prior, you could calculate this as a `DateTime`: `var yesterdayStartTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date + paragem.HoraInico;` - it also means that your code is a little clearer to anyone reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `TimeSpan`.

When your program starts:

```
paragem.HoraInico = DateTime.Now; // Declare as DateTime not TimeSpan
```

And then when you need to check:

```
TempoTotalParagem = DateTime.Now - paragem.HoraInico; // Difference of DateTimes is TimeSpan
```